# Combined format of SASS instructions

Tags: cuda

I haven't seen a cuda document that describes the combined form of SASS instructions. For example, I know what are `IADD` and `IMAD`. But

```
IMAD.IADD R8, R8, 0x1, R7 ;
```

are not clear. Which operand belongs to which opcode? How that is executed? Moreover, are we dealing with *one ADD* and *one MAD* which means *two ADD* and *one MUL*? Or that is considered as one *one MADD* which means *one ADD* and *one MUL*?

How about `IMAD.MOV.U32 R5, RZ, RZ, 0x0 ;`? How that is interpreted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Volta and Turing architecture have two primary execution pipes.

1. FMA pipe is responsible for FFMA, FMUL, FADD, FSWZADD, and IMAD instructions.
2. ALU pipe is responsible for integer (except IMAD), bit manipulation, logical, and data movement instructions.

The ALU pipe executes *MOV* and *IADD3*.
The FMA pipe executes *IMAD* including variants *IMAD.IADD* and *IMAD.MOV*.

Using IMAD to emulate IADD and MOV allows the compiler to explicitly schedule instructions to FMA pipe instead of the ALU pipe.

What's clear from compiler output is that the compiler is emulating binary integer add and raw moves with `IMAD`, which generalizes both.  The suffix is just the disassembler being nice by matching the pattern and telling you the operation is semantically equivalent to a simpler operation.  The `IMAD.*` sequences are clever using `RZ` (the zero register), `0x0` and `0x1` to accomplish this.  When the disassembler sees such a pattern, it adds the `.MOV` op suffix to say, *"Hey, this is just a simple move."*

E.g.

```
IMAD.IADD R8, R8, 0x1, R7
```

is:

```
R8 = 1*R8 + R7 = R8 + R7
IADD R8, R8, R7
```

(If `IADD` existed.)

Similarly for the `MOV` case, you see that it's using `RZ`. It's emulating the following.

```
MOV R5, 0x0
```

There is a `MOV` op in Volta, but I almost never see it.

(There's also a left-shift-by-K version `IMAD.SHL` I think, which uses a multiplier of *2^K* where *K* is the shift amount.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I still don't know why nvcc uses such a format? Do you mean that `IMAD.IADD` is really two instructions `IMAD R8, R8, 0x1, R7` and `IADD R8, R8, R7` executed by GPU?

Comment: If it's easier to think of it elide the suffixes. `IADD` and `IMOV` don't really exist in the instruction set, only `IMAD` exists. The GPU is just using `IMAD` to emulate those simpler operations. An instruction which computes `a*b+c` can be used for simpler expressions `a*b` (as `a*b+0`), `a+c` (as `a*1+c`), and `a` (as `a*1+0`).

Comment: According to the instruction set reference for volta, `IADD` and `IMAD` exist.  See https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#volta so i disagree with your comment.

Comment: You're partly right, my memory is hazy.  I'll update my answer.  (BTW: I think you mean `IADD` and *`MOV`* in your comment.)  But now I do remember a `MOV` with a weird optional muxing capability but which is never used in CUDA (the muxing).  Maybe it uses a `MOV` uses a different pipe in the SM and the compiler sees better perf with the integer pipe?